# Can a bash script monitor what a program prints to screen?

Tags: bash, shell-script

So the problem stems from having a slow internet connection, and I have problems (debian) when I try to run 'apt-get update'.
Apt-get pulls down 4 small pieces of data and tries to pull down 1 large piece, after about 5 minutes and 25% complete it gives up on the large download and instead tries to get an even larger alternative. 5 minutes after that it gives up at 20% done and instead tries another even lager alternative, and 5 minutes later and 10% done it gives up and complains it could not get what it needs. If I try running 'apt-get update' again it pulls down the 4 small pieces again and sequentially continues the 3 large pieces from where it left each of them. I have tried researching and playing with apt's settings for http::Timeout and ftp::Timeout, but it seems like there isn't a setting to deal with this situation. My current practice is to babysit this and ctrl-c when apt moves on to an alternative, to avoid the extra wasted 10 minutes per attempt. I want to be able to get it to babysit itself.

What I have in mind is a shell script along the lines of:

start a timeout,
sudo apt-get update,
if at any time apt-get completes successfully then immediately go on to run sudo apt full-upgrade and eventually exit,
but in the meantime if apt-get prints a line to screen beginning with the text "Ign:" then pkill apt,
and if less than 30 minutes have expired then start over from sudo apt-get update,
else echo "Apt-update could not complete at this time!" and exit.

What I would like to know is, can a bash script actually do such stuff? If yes then a tip on what command to start looking up would be helpful. I think the checking and the running of apt-get would have to be in 2 processes but I don't know how one would check the screen output and exit status of the other. If a bash script can't do it then I have no idea what other tool I should look at, can Python do it?

Comment: XY problem! Fix the network problem first, rather than kludging in corrective hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a complex question here.

1. Can a script monitor what a program prints to the screen?

Yes, `strace` can do this.

```bsh
strace -p<process id> -s1000 -e write
```

This will watch what the process belonging to process id is writing, increasing the output to 1000 chars from default 32.

2. Can you do things when a command outputs some string?

This is pretty simple and should get you going in the right direction.

```bsh
<command-you-want-to-watch> | tee file_to_watch
```

`tee` will output to the screen as well as to a file. Although, you might not get some of the fancy overwriting on the screen that normally happens. If you don't care about watching, you can just redirect output to the file `<command> >file`.

watcher script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  if grep -q "phrase1" file_to_watch; then
    #do stuff
    break
  fi

  if grep -q "phrase2" file_to_watch; then
    #do stuff
    break
  fi

  sleep 1
done
```

This will check the file once per second for a phrase, do whatever you like and then end (the `break` statements are what kill the infinite loop)